# Only style one child when another child in parent exists

Tags: css, sass

Below is my HTML structure

```
<div class="ContentHeader">
   <hgroup>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subtitle</h2>
   </hgroup>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a solution to the issue that doesn't use javascript, I know I can do that but I'd prefer if there was a CSS only solution.

I want to only style the `h1`, if the `h2` also exists. So, if there is no `h2`, then there is no styling applied to the `h1`.

I tried this but it only styled the h2

```
.ContentHeader hgroup h1 + h2 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
.ContentHeader hgroup h1:nth-last-child(2) { /* your code here */}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you, didn't think of using `nth-last-child`

Answer (score 1):

You can make both of the headings to same element.

```
<div class="ContentHeader">
   <hgroup>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h1>Subtitle</h1>
   </hgroup>
</div>
```

Then you can use only child property in CSS

```
.ContentHeader hgroup h1:only-child {padding-bottom: 10px;}
```

See here:

```css
.ContentHeader hgroup h1:only-child  {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ContentHeader">
   <hgroup>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2>Subtitle</h2>
   </hgroup>
</div>

<div class="ContentHeader">
   <hgroup>
      <h1>Title</h1>
   </hgroup>
</div>
```

Comment: For SEO purposes we only use one H1 per page, multiple h1's makes it difficult for Google to contextualise the page.

Comment: I agree, then you can wrap headings in two hgroups or div's with same class and then use only-child pseudo class on that class

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in css (nor sass). Css does not look back. Styling an element that's after another element is possible, not the other way around.

You can possibly achieve the same result by not giving a padding/margin bottom to the `h1`, but a padding/margin top to the `h2`. If that will not help you, javascript is probably your only option.